# IBM MobileFirst 8.0 integrate with Integration Bus

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, ibm-integration-bus

For our mobile apps we implemented our adapters using JavaScript where procedures simply do `MFP.Server.invokeHTTP`. But now we need somehow integrate with IBM Integration Bus (IIB), and I can't find any information how to do it. 
I have only limited knowledge how Integration Bus works and why it needs.

Is it possible to do it with JavaScript or it possible only in Java (also all examples, that I found - it simple how to create services for IIB)?

Should we configure MobileFirst Server (via Operation Console) to connect to IIB or we need import additional packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it correct you are already calling web services via HTTP .

IIB provides you web services like REST SOAP... in your case you can simply ask your team (IIB ) to build services as REST and expose them... from you mobile server you can simply call them like any other service... like you can provide the IIB rest service url in you http method and get resoonse back.

Comment: Build services as REST/SOAP - these are standard feature of IIB, right? So it shouldn't take long, right?
And as I understand these services will work as 3rd party application and ofcourse will be secured. How in this case it is the best to implement authorization to invoke them?

Comment: As I understood from docs, it is neccessary to create a separate flow, that will handle all requests and handle incoming requests